# inequality with sum and product

Tags: inequality, convexity-inequality

Let $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in (\mathbb{R}_+)^n$.
How can I prove that
$$2\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n x_k - \prod_1^n x_k^{1/n}\right) \ge \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\left(x_k - \prod_1^n x_j^{1/n}\right)^2$$

Note :  all the sums and products start at $k=1$ (but i didn't manage to write with  LaTeX)

Comment: Write `\sum_{k=1}^n`

Comment: Let the $x_i$ have maximum $M$, arithmetic mean $\mu$, geometric mean $\rho$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and define $d:=\mu-\rho\in[0,\,M]$ so your inequality is $2Md\ge\Bbb E(X-\rho)^2=d^2+\sigma^2$, i.e. $M^2-(M-d)^2\ge \sigma^2$. Not sure how helpful that is.

Comment: A useful mathjax trick, particularly for beginners: If you see some formatting that someone else has done and you want to know how they did it, right-click on the formula and select "Show Math As > TeX Commands", and it will open up a window with the fomatting in it.